# How to reload div using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to reload only the div without reloading page.

Comment: Google should be your first attempt to find out...

Comment: @gdoron I know. I couldn't find a good solution by googling. That why I post the question.

Comment: look at the first result of [this](http://www.google.co.il/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+load) search in google

Comment: @gdoron I tried before. It's not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

you question is vast scoped but you can try follwing Ajax will be do your requirement e.g. **without reloading page.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

<body>
<div id="load_tweets"> </div>
</body>

</script>


<div id="loaddiv">
</div>
```

Now finally you need to write the code for the file “reload.php” which will extract the contends from the other page or it also may contain the code to read the data from the database depending upon requirement.
here i am going to read a small content from another site. you can copy , paste the code and save it as the filename “reload.php”. in the same folder that contains the source code.

```
echo"<img src='http://www.nepalstock.com/datanepse/realindex.php'/>";
```

see [live demo here](http://www.designgala.com/demos/divref/a3.html)
refer article [How to refresh DIV using jquery](http://designgala.com/how-to-refresh-div-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on where you want to get the HTML fragment from. For example if it is a server side script that returns it you could use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to send an AJAX request to it and replace the contents of the div with it without navigating away from the page:

```
$('#divId').load('/myscript');
```